# Can I serve a directory with express without bypassing authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-ad-b2c

I have a bunch of legacy html files I would like to serve to authenticated users.
The authentication provider is Azure AD B2C and I found this [Nodejs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/nodejs-web-api-azure-ad/) template that authenticates users with AD B2C.

I can serve single html files and authenticate them with something like this.

```js
app.get('/hello',
    passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {session: false}),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log('Validated claims: ', req.authInfo);
        
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "files/index.html");
    }
);
```

But I don't want make a `app.get()` call for all ~100 files. I know I can use something like

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

to serve directories. But the files will become public and I still wish to authenticate them using the `passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {session: false})`.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
app.get('/public/:fileName',
    passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {session: false}),
    (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + req.params.fileName);
    }
);
```